# Process files that don't fit in memory with Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bigdata

I have a big tar file (700GB in total) which contains a few millions of XML files. Those XML files have a lot of garbage data and I try to parse them, get the details I need and store them in a CSV instead.

My first step was to split the tar file in smaller (~1-1.5GB each) files. Now, I need to go through all the tar files, read them, get the info and store it in 2 different CSV files.

My code:

```
import tarfile
import csv  
import glob 
from multiprocessing import Process
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main(index, tar_file):

    tar = tarfile.open(tar_file)

    file1 = open('file1_' + str(index) + '.csv', "w")
    file2 = open('file2_' + str(index) + '.csv', "w")

    writer1 = csv.writer(file1, delimiter=',')
    writer2 = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',')

    for member in tar:
        if member.isreg() and member.name.endswith('.xml'): # regular xml file
            with closing(tar.extractfile(member)) as xmlfile:
                root = ET.parse(xmlfile).getroot()
                if <statement>:
                    #get the data I want from root
                    writer1.writerow(<some data>)

                if <statement>:   
                    #get the data I want from root      
                    writer2.writerow(<some data>)
    workFile.close()
    peerFile.close()  
    tar.close()               

if __name__ == '__main__':

    files = [f for f in glob.glob("data/*.tar", recursive=True)]  
    procs = []
    for index, f in enumerate(files):
        proc = Process(target=main, args=(index, f,))
        procs.append(proc)
        proc.start()

    for proc in procs:
        proc.join()
```

I did it like that, so I don't keep anything in memory and write the file line by line. However, after a while of running the above code, my laptop just turned off. I guess, there is a part on the code that fill up the memory. How can I handle this case without the need to read everything right away?

Comment: If memory were the problem, I'd expect the [oom killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) to kill your process(es). The fact that your laptop turned off points to a different problem, and one that may not be being handled properly by your system (hardware or software).

Comment: Having split a 700GB file into 1-1.5GB smaller files, this still leaves you with on the order of 500 files to deal with.  You are starting up a new process for every file, so about 500 processes.  

After you reach the number of computing cores on your machine (minus 1), you will not see any efficiency gains.  You are cramming so many processes into your machine, that might be the reason is shutdown.

A better solution would be to use the `ProcessPoolExecutor` from the `concurrent.futures` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't really clear why your laptop turns off. It may be some bad combination of "out of memory" and "out of file descriptors" (you spawn lots of processes, and each opens 3 files, yes?) and possibly a bug in your OS or malfunction of some hardware.

Either way you can try to avoid it simply by reducing the number of spawned processes. First of all there is no gain from spawning a process per file. The rule of thumb is: never spawn more than, say [3 x number of cores] parallel functions (usually just [number of cores] is enough when you do purely CPU intensive tasks, but you do have a small amount of i/o as well).

So instead of

```py
files = [f for f in glob.glob("data/*.tar", recursive=True)]  
procs = []
for index, f in enumerate(files):
    proc = Process(target=main, args=(index, f,))
    procs.append(proc)
    proc.start()

for proc in procs:
    proc.join()
```

try this

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
pool = Pool(2*cpu_count())  # or 3, do some empirical testing
files = [f for f in glob.glob("data/*.tar", recursive=True)]  
procs = []
for index, f in enumerate(files):
    pool.apply_async(main, (index, f,))

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Read more about pools here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

If you are using Python3.x you can also try executors: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html